# In Pandas, how do I create groups by using a function?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have the following DataFrame:

```
data = np.random.randn(10,10)
col = list('ABCDEFGHIJ')
idx = list('ababaaccab')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = col, index = idx)

df

          A         B         C         D         E         F         H  
a -0.104171 -0.872001  1.459766 -0.026101  0.474336  2.032986 -0.795409   
b  0.778402  0.965868  1.672520 -2.463641  1.024571  1.501360  1.047823   
a  0.731303 -1.314826  1.477969 -1.018818  0.539794 -0.108252  0.038276   
b -1.180857 -1.931064 -0.287966 -0.387748 -0.324306  0.146812  0.674937   
a -0.151452  0.387804  0.853088  0.610810  0.091901 -0.246471 -0.677219   
a  1.392482  1.286639 -0.607495  0.682221  0.164414 -0.496787  0.502786   
c  0.039890  0.587645  0.577257 -0.381706 -1.477829  1.165732 -1.877052   
c -1.307827 -0.370028  0.136269 -0.968533  0.830933 -0.025641 -0.497450   
a  0.990024  0.003812 -0.698894  0.674133 -0.176148 -0.184096 -1.449170   
b -1.214920 -1.123358 -0.847955 -0.464895  0.517553 -0.080168 -1.162767
```

I also use the function from pandas document that separates the letter between 'vowel' and 'consonant'

```
def get_letter_type(letter):
    if letter.lower() in 'aeiou':
        return 'v'
    else:
        return 'c'
```

My question is how I can do groupby using letter type from the index of my dataframe?

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 3):

When you pass a function to the `groupby`, it evaluates the function on the index. So, if the values are in the index, you can just do:

```
df.groupby(get_letter_type).sum()
Out[122]: 
          A         B         C         D         E         F         G  \
c  5.504182  3.637560  2.659321  0.558187  0.206418 -1.194616  1.410917   
v  1.132699 -0.768438 -0.183739 -1.353405  1.148394 -0.668739 -1.376241   

          H         I         J  
c  3.388815 -1.086567 -2.223479  
v  0.456455 -0.904328  1.072830
```

---

For a more general case, you can use [`np.vectorize`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) to get a vectorized version of your function:

```
import numpy as np    
get_letter_type_vectorized = np.vectorize(get_letter_type)
```

Then use that function for grouping with your index as the argument (would work for any other input than index):

```
df.groupby(get_letter_type_vectorized(df.index)).sum()
```

---

If the dataset is large, you can try your own vectorized version with `np.where` as well:

```
df.groupby(np.where(df.index.isin(list("aeiou")), "v", "c")).sum()
```

`np.where` will return an array of v's and c's (`array(['v', 'c', 'v', 'c', 'v', 'v', 'c', 'c', 'v', 'c'], dtype='<U1')`) and the grouping will be done on that array.

Comment: nice! wasn't aware of `np.vectorize()` function

Comment: @MaxU I find it very useful although as it's stated in the docs it's basically a loop so there are no performance benefits. For big datasets it may be better to look for an actual vectorization.

Comment: your `df.groupby(np.where(df.index.isin(list("aeiou")), "v", "c")).sum()` version is approx. 2.3 times faster on 100.000 DF and 2.7 times faster compared to piRSquared's version

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

#### Setup

```
np.random.seed(314)
data = np.random.randn(10,10)
col = list('ABCDEFGHIJ')
idx = list('ababaaccab')
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = col, index = idx)


def get_letter_type(letter):
    if letter.lower() in 'aeiou':
        return 'v'
    else:
        return 'c'
```

#### Solution

Append the letter type to `df.index` and define new `DataFrame`.  Then use `groupby(level=1)`

```
letter_types = df.index.to_series().apply(get_letter_type)
df_w_letter_types = df.set_index(letter_types, append=True)
letter_type_groupby = df_w_letter_types.groupby(level=1)
```

#### Demonstration

Then you can do whatever you want

```
print letter_type_groupby.sum()

          A         B         C         D         E         F         G  \
c  0.155376 -0.544616 -2.274168 -0.721236 -1.214174  0.663555  2.668149   
v -1.196059 -0.264262 -0.252973  1.178112  0.030117 -0.392086  3.503615   

          H         I         J  
c  2.951569 -3.216444  3.976823  
v -2.790688 -0.343123 -4.346544
```

Comment: This is a nice solution but you don't need to append the generated column to your df for grouping (as an index or as a column). You can just do: `df.groupby(letter_types).sum()`

Comment: @ayhan Yeah!  I learned that from your answer.  Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can try something like this:

```
for letters in list(df.index):
    A = get_letter_type(letters)
    if A == 'v':
        print df.index.values
    else:
        continue
```